# Addition of two time values are poping up undesired duration

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I just wrote a code to see the addition of two time durations which are in `hh:mm:ss` format;but not getting the one I am looking for.

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Dim v1 : v1 = #20:20:10#
Dim v2 : v2 = #20:20:10#

MsgBox (v1 + v2)
```

**OUTPUT** Coming as `12/31/1899 4:40:20 PM`

Could you guide me here?

**Update**

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Dim V1 : v1 = #20:20:10#
Dim V2 : v2 = #20:42:10#

MsgBox (Hour(V1) + Hour(V2)) & ":" & Minute(V1) + Minute(V2) & ":" & Second(V1) + Second(V2)
```

**Output** Coming as `40:62:20`

[image: Undesired]

**UPDATED CODE**

```
SumDate = "00:00:00" 

For IndexSearch = 0 To ArrayListTaskDetails.Count - 1 Step 4

dt1 = ArrayListTaskDetails(IndexSearch + 3)         
SumDate = TimeAdd(dt1,SumDate)

Loop

Function TimeAdd(dt1,dt2)

If (IsDate(dt1) And IsDate(dt2)) = False Then
TimeAdd = "00:00:00"
Exit Function
End If

TimeAdd = Hour(dt1)+Hour(dt2) & ":" & Minute(dt1)+Minute(dt2) & ":" & Second(dt1)+Second(dt2)
End Function
```

Comment: As per The logic `4M01` I have corrected my code ,please guide me here if I did anything wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now minutes and seconds are normalized:

```
Sub SummingTimes()


  Dim v1: v1 = #8:32:33 PM#
  Dim v2: v2 = #8:32:33 PM#
  Dim hours As Variant
  Dim minutes As Variant
  Dim seconds As Variant
  Dim timetext As String


     seconds = Second(v1) + Second(v2)
      minutes = Int(seconds / 60)
       seconds = seconds - minutes * 60
        minutes = minutes + Minute(v1) + Minute(v2)
       hours = Int(minutes / 60)
      minutes = minutes - hours * 60
     hours = hours + Hour(v1) + Hour(v2)
   timetext = hours & ":" & minutes & ":" & seconds
  MsgBox timetext

End Sub
```

Messagebox shows `41:5:6`. If you want to get `41:05:06`, some string operations are needed.
Excel spreadsheet: http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Summing_hh-mm-ss.xls

Comment: My input is different from yours: I have `2*(20:32:33)=40 hours + 64 minutes + 66 seconds = 40h65m6s=41h5m6s`

Comment: this is correct,but I think your input in the code is something different,thus i got confused!

Comment: I continued the snippet from morning, so skipped all the discussion examples inbetween.

Comment: @JüriRuut `Dim v1 : v1 = #120:20:10#` and `Dim v2 : v2 = #20:42:10#` your code is not running!

Comment: @CodeLover What does it do? Error message, erroneous output?

Comment: If you try the code with the above input you would get an error `Syntax mismatch` kind of !

Comment: I managed to take a closer look. Valid time and date formats should be included between the hashes (`#`) . My VBA editor adjusts automatically `#20:42:10#`to PM time format, `#120:20:10#` gives syntax error without compiling. http://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/VHK123/LT423111411.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TimeValue` function that returns a Variant of subtype Date that contains the time.

```
 Option Explicit

Dim v1 : v1 = #20:20:10#
Dim v2 : v2 = #20:20:10#

MsgBox (TimeValue(v1 + v2))
```

**EDIT:-**

AFAIK, there no direct way to do such addition even if you use `FormatDateTime(date,format)` with format `vbLongTime` You have to use normal logic of addition & printing hours, min & then sec like below code

```
  Option Explicit 
  Dim v1 : v1 = #20:20:10#
  Dim v2 : v2 = #20:20:10#
  Msgbox Hour(v1)+Hour(v1)&":"&Minute(v1)+Minute(v2)&":"&Second(v1)+Second(v2)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got the output `4:40:20` but it is still not the one I am looking for it should be like `40:40:20`. Please advice!

Comment: `MsgBox (Hour(V1) + Hour(V2)) & ":" & Minute(V1) + Minute(V2) & ":" & Second(V1) + Second(V2)`

Comment: @4M01 I agree but what would be the scenario when `Minute` addition will give the hours? which was being taken care of by your previous function `TimeValue()`. The only thing is not happening that Hours are not coming appropriately. but `minute` and `seconds` are handled properly!

Comment: @4M01 Please see me EDIT, Hours and Minutes are not adjusted!

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Excel are stored internally as number of days since 1/1/1900.
Therefore 1 day = 1.
Therefore 1 hour = 1/24.
With this logic, 20 hours + 20 hours returns a date, which I would expect to be Jan 2,1900 at 4pm (40-24).
I am not expert in VbScript, but in VBA you could solve the problem by using a custom format:
`MsgBox Format(v1 + v2, "[hh]:mm")`
The [] around the hh are forcing values the hours display to be applied to the entire value, not just the fractional part.

Another solution, is to multiply timevalues by 24. That returns "decimal hours".
`MsgBox  (#20:00# + #20:30#)*24` returns 40.5, like you would expect.

Comment: @iDevelop +1 for your explanation

Comment: @iDevelop  Yes you are right,I need to do such circulations with 18 columns in my excel using VBScript.So at run-time calculation I am fearing to have such data issues.Thus I wrote the above snippet.What I suspected is coming out and so how prevent this, Any Idea?